# Where are Custom Menus saved in the Database for Wordpress 3.0?

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I've been searching and searching my sql database in phpmyadmin but I can't seem to find where custom menus are stored in the database. Anyone know where it's stored? I have a large menu basically that takes forever to create. I'm in development now and rather than recreating it in production I want to try and copy the sql over to see if it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The actual menu titles, IDs, and names are stored in the wp_terms table.

Comment: `$menu_list = get_terms('nav_menu');` will return all menus.

Comment: This query returns only the menu ID. What query returns each menu item with enough information to regenerate the menu?

Comment: Once you have the menu ID, you can run 
`$wp_menu_items  = wp_get_nav_menu_items( $id );`

Answer (score 73):

When new custom menu is added, its entry is added into several tables.

1. table: `_term_taxonomy` with a column `taxonomy` and value `nav_menu`.
2. from 1) `term_id` is also in table:`_terms` with the title of menu which is shown in admin panel
3. table:`_term_relationship` will contain `term_texonomy_id` from 1) and connection to all object_id which will be linked to all `_post` table having `sub_menu` and below level menu.
4. table:`_postmeta` will contain all the details related to menu and submenu for each `object_id` from `_posts` table.

Comment: I don't understand how this isn't upvoted. I was looking for a way to export and import the menus. I know my answer. Don't. I ll do it manually.

Comment: Should clarify step 3 to say that the object_id from term_relationships is equal to the id field from wp_post

Comment: I have uninstalled WP Fastest Cache and after finishing the uninstall process left an entry on the left menu and I cannot find it anywhere on the tables you say...

Answer (score 33):

Navigation menu items are stored in the wp_posts table with `post_type = 'nav_menu_item'`.

Comment: But what custom post type?

Comment: how wrong is this, wordpress bloats the _posts and _options tables throwing all kinds of things in there that should be placed in a seperate table for better database management and loading speed

Comment: Yes, the database is very poorly normalized and this answer is only partially correct. It identifies the objects that comprise the menu but doesn't provide the values (e.g. menu text) associated with the menu. I am still digging to try to find that data.

Answer (score 16):

I hate to bump a old thread. But if anyone runs into this like I did searching for the answer, as of `WP 3.2` the `post_type` for menu is now called `nav_menu_item`  in the `wp_posts` table. They didn't have that on the wp page, they just had `nav_menu`. Which I couldn't find.

Answer (score 13):

The custom menu links are in the `wp_postmeta` table under `"meta_value"`
    meta_key = _menu_item_url

Comment: Check out [WordPress Answers](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/), Stack Exchange's WordPress question and answer site.  It would be great if you could share some of your expertise.  BTW WordCamp Phoenix was great!

Comment: @Chris_O Hey man! thanks.. I've seen it I just rarely get on stack..... sites. I should try and hang out there more often :/  #toobusy

Comment: @Chris_O fyi, I do have an account there: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/2173/ryno

Answer (score 7):

I wanted to provide a more complete and up to date answer for people who stumble upon this post like I did. There are several places in the database that need to be checked/updated if you're wanting to manually insert or update menu items.

The first step is finding your main menu container. This is stored in `wp_terms`. Just search by `name` for the name of your menu. Take note of the ID. In my example this will be `33`. Likewise, you could insert a new row here to create a new menu. The slug can't have spaces in it. Just substitute in `-` instead.

Now we'll get to finding items in that menu. Those are stored in `wp_posts` with a `post_type` of `nav_menu_item`. There's nothing in this table that ties it to your ID above, so you'll have to go by `post_title`. If the goal is inserting a new menu item, with phpMyAdmin you can just click `Copy` on an existing item in any menu and change `post_title` and `post_name`. Now take note of the ID of the item you inserted. Mine is 9179. It will also be nice to take note of the ID of the item you copied (even better if it was from the same menu) as we'll be using that in the next step.

Now go to `wp_postmeta` and search on the `post_id` field for the item we just copied. This will bring up all of the fields that need to be filled in to get the info for our new menu item. Using phpMyAdmin copy each of those entries and change as needed. `_menu_item_menu_item_parent`, `_menu_item_target`, and `_menu_item_classes` are the fields that will most likely need changing. And make sure you're putting the ID of your new item (9179) in `_menu_item_object_id`.

After those are all created we can now tie that menu item to our menu. We need to get the `term_taxonomy_id` from `wp_term_taxonomy`. Just search `term_id` using the ID from the first step, 33 for me. The `term_taxonomy_id` happens to be 33 for me as well. No we need to insert a new row into `wp_term_relationships`. `object_id` will be your post id (9179) and `term_taxonomy_id` is what we just looked up (33).

Now your new item should be in your menu.

Comment: Hideous schema. Thanks though.

Answer (score 4):

Here are the SQL scripts I used:

Get the menus from the wp_term table:

```
SELECT * FROM wp_terms AS t LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy AS tt ON tt.term_id = t.term_id WHERE tt.taxonomy = 'nav_menu'
```

Use the term_id to get get all of the menu titles / links from all the other connected tables. In my opinion this is a terrible relational database.  Just replace the tt.term_id with yours from the query above, below is 11.

```
SELECT p.post_title, p.post_name, p.menu_order, pm.meta_value FROM wp_posts AS p LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships AS tr ON tr.object_id = p.ID LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy AS tt ON tt.term_taxonomy_id = tr.term_taxonomy_id INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS pm ON p.Id = pm.post_id WHERE p.post_type = 'nav_menu_item' AND tt.term_id = 11 AND pm.meta_key = '_menu_item_url'
```

Answer (score 2):

Each menu item are saved in posts table and menu hierarchy/options/urls etc. belonging to these items are stored in postmeta table. In postmeta table you can see post_id column belonging to posts table items.

Answer (score -4):

```
$postId = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare("SELECT post_id FROM `wp_postmeta` WHERE meta_key='_menu_item_object_id' AND `meta_value`='$id'"));
$postIdc = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare("SELECT post_id FROM `wp_postmeta` WHERE meta_key='_menu_item_object_id' AND `meta_value`='$a[1]'"));
$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM `wp_postmeta` WHERE meta_key='_menu_item_menu_item_parent' AND `meta_value`='$postId'";
$sql2c = "SELECT * FROM `wp_postmeta` WHERE meta_key='_menu_item_menu_item_parent' AND `meta_value`='$postIdc'";
```

Comment: Try to put a little more information into your answer.  "Just code" doesn't help us understand the why or the how this addresses the question.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker how is this an answer at all?